# Create custom z values for a line in 3D view

Tags: qgis, line, geometry, 3d-map, z-value

I have a line which I load in the 3D view but want this line to not be on the ground but rather in the air at a certain height above ground.

Comment: could you specify which file format you are working in?

Answer (score 1):

1. Right-click your line `Export` > `Save feature as...`
2. Under geometry use `Include Z-dimension`
   [image]
3. Re-import the just created line and under `Processing toolbox` > `Set Z Value`
4. Choose a Z-value and save to a new file
   [image]

############################

If you want your Line to be at a specific height over the ground you can use the `Drape (Set Z Value from Raster)` Tool to sample the height from a DEM. Subsequently you would need the raster calculator to add the desired height to your lines Z value.

Comment: Thanks tried all the suggestions but nothing working.....even when i try the drape function and then open the resultant attribute file no z column created?

Comment: A z value is not stored in an attribute-column.

Comment: as @MrXsquared already said: the z-value is stored in the geometry. If you want to export it you could use points instead of a line and then export the z-values from the geometry by using the field calculator > create new column > $z. If your goail is not to display but to export the z-value maybe re-formulate your question.